# Not drawing outside bounds when clipToBounds=NO

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, core-graphics

I am drawing lines on a map, and I notice that my annotation view isn't covering the entire area of the lines (which is fine, as long as I can draw outside the bounds of the view).

Here is a picture of what I'm experiencing.  The clipToBounds property is set to NO for the annotation view, and I've added a semi-transparent color to the background so you can see the position of the view.
[blue line not drawn outside bounds http://img.skitch.com/20100512-qdm18j7x42wptw3cumnr6h271q.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100512-qdm18j7x42wptw3cumnr6h271q.jpg)

The pins represent the various waypoints on the map.

Do I have to do something special to get the lines to keep drawing outside the bounds of the view?

Comment: The linked image has disappeared which makes this question harder to understand. Any chance you can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What lines are you referring to?

Anyway, I think the answer should be "no", unless you are doing custom drawing.

In that case, you need to make sure `[view setNeedsDisplay]` is being called whenever the lines need to be drawn.

Comment: I am doing custom drawing...  The blue view you see is a MKAnnotationView, and it's centered over the first waypoint on the map.

I'm updating the drawing every time the map changes via the MKMapViewDelegate methods.  It draws everything that's inside the view, but nothing outside.

Comment: Oh, and the line I'm referring to is the blue line that follows the pins.